# Tricky SQL query to get all unmatched record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a tricky SQL query that should lists to me all unmatched destinations. But there is parent-child relation in destination table. So if a matched destination has an unmatched child destination both parent and child should be listed. I tried to create a table to visualize it. I hope I would help to understand better way.

I tried to write below query bot it did not work

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table_A AS ParentTable
WHERE
    ID NOT IN (SELECT TableA_ID FROM Table_B WHERE TableA_ID IS NOT NULL)
    -- this is to find UNmatched records
    AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * FROM Table_A AS ChildTable
           WHERE ChildTable.Parent = ParentTable.Code)
           -- this is the part that I was not sure (:
```

Here is main destination table

```
TABLE A  
ID      Destination                     ParentID
1       France                          0
2       Île-De-France                   1
3       Ablis                           2
4       Provence-Alpes-Cote D'azur      1
5       Aix-En-Provence                 4
```

Here is the second table

```
TABLE B
ID      Destination                     TableA_ID
100     France                          1
101     Île-De-France                   2
102     Ablis                           NULL
103     Provence-Alpes-Cote D'azur      4
104     Aix-En-Provence                 5
```

In this situation I need to retrieve below table since "Ablis" not matched.

```
RESULTING TABLE
ID      Destination                     ParentID
1       France                          0
2       Île-De-France                   1
3       Ablis                           2
```

Comment: If `'Ablis'` wasn't matched, why are the rows `'Île-De-France`' and `'France'` being returned. Is it because they are the parents of `'Ablis'`?

Comment: yes. because I have master-detail grid view to show results to user to match unmatched destinations. otherwise it would be very easy (:

Comment: _"bot it did not work"_ is not a problem description. What happened? Why was that wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a recursive cte like below.

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/BTOKG58741)**</kbd>

```
; with rcte as 
(
    SELECT
    A.id, A.destination, A.parentid
    FROM
    TABLE_B b join TABLE_A a on a.destination=b.destination WHERE TableA_ID IS NULL
 union all
 select 
 T.id, T.destination, T.parentid
    from
    table_A T join rcte r 
    on r.parentid=t.id
 )

 select * from rcte order by parentid asc
```

Comment: it works but I guess I forgot to mentions one thing. some records in table A is absent in Table B. so your code work perfectly. but if you show me a way to get absent record it would great. bye the way thanks for answer.

Comment: I have found a way to achive that. I added UNION ALL SELECT A.Id, A.destination, A.Parentid FROM  Table_A AS a WHERE A.Id NOT IN (SELECT TableA_ID  FROM Table_B WHERE TableA_ID  IS NOT NULL) before rcte join and added a distinct to select part. But I am not sure that this is the best way..

Answer (score 1):

I would use `not exist` with recursive `CTE`

```
with t as (
    select Id, Destination, ParentID 
    from table_a a
    where not exists (select 1 from table_b where a.id = TableA_ID)  
    union all
    select t.Id, t.Destination, t.ParentID 
    from t c join table_a a1
             on t.id = c.ParentID
)
select * from t
order by 3;
```